# Node.js https key and certificat

Tags: node.js, https

Hi,
I tried creating a pem key and csr using openssl for windows :

#### Test 1

```
OpenSSL> req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key_localhost.pem -out cert_localhost.pem -days 365
```

That created 2 files names `key_localhost.pem` and `cert_localhost.pem`. I pasted both files to the same level of my server.js file. However my browser been getting a security problem.

Display on the browser :

```
The certificate is not safe because it is self-signed.
The most valid certificate only for. 
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

Here is my server.js

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('key_localhost1.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert_localhost1.pem'),
    passphrase: 'localhost',
  }, app).listen(8080);
```

#### Test 2

I tried another thing :

```
openssl> req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out key_localhost2.pem
openssl> x509 -req -days 365 -in key_localhost2.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert_localhost2.crt
```

That created three file names `key_localhost.pem`, `cert_localhost.pem` and `key.pem`. But nothings change on my browser...

Here is my server.js

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert_localhost2.crt'),
    passphrase: 'localhost',
  }, app).listen(8080);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your error message is in French, and it is a picture so I can't copy/paste it into Google Translate, but I think it says that you are using a self-signed certificate, so the browser can't trust it. You **are** using a self-signed certificate, so this is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem: self-signed certificates, as the one you're using, are considered to be a security risk. A trusted (by the browser) CA (Certification Authority) needs to sign your keys before the browser will deem them secure. One such CA is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

There's a module called [`auto-sni`](https://github.com/DylanPiercey/auto-sni) that can automate requesting certificates from Let's Encrypt. I've never used this module myself, so no idea how well it works.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try to follow tutorial on *Let's Encrypt* and maybe test *auto-sni*. I'don't understand why in openssl tutorial that I followed nobody tolk of CA...?

Answer (score -1):

I think browser is asking you to add the exception. You can follow any of the below links:
https://superuser.com/questions/632059/how-to-add-a-self-signed-certificate-as-an-exception-in-chrome

[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/15076602#15076602)